# Wrong parameters are passed. Java

Tags: java

I am having issues passing the values of the paramarized construcor as an object in another class.

```
public class Client {

   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;
   private long phoneNum;
   private String email;

   public Client (String firstName, String lastName, long phoneNum, String email) {  }
}
```

---

```
public class Account {

    private long accountNum;
    private double balance;
    private Client client = new Client(null, null, accountNum, null);
    private Random random = new Random();
 }
```

In the Account class it String, String, Long, String. It is taking the long value in the account class and putting it into the Client parameter. How do I pass the parameters I specified in the Client class?

Comment: What is the compilation error you are getting?

Comment: @codeLover I am not getting a compilation error. Its just not passing through the proper parameters.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't?

Comment: have you try to print inside your called constructor. how can you say that passing value is not correctly send.

Comment: For other parameters you can use getter and setter. When your object is initialise with parameters then after you can set other parameter values.

Comment: @ShellDragon In the account class, accountNum is one of the parameters. But in Client it is the phoneNum. Why isn't it passing through as phoneNum in the Account class?

Comment: because the value of the variable is passed not the variable name.

Comment: I am guessing your intention. Try changing `long` to `Long` or do the initialization of Client and Random objects inside the constructor of  Account class, after you're done initializing account number. `long` is a primitive type

Comment: @TNT That worked. Thank you. I did that in the called constructor.

Comment: Saving a phone number as `long` looks suspicious. It will work though if you _always_ and _only ever_ store international phone numbers starting with a `+`. There are two entirely different meanings of the word number, which in German are called Nummer (like in house number, may include letters), and Zahl (mathematical numbers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add getter and setter for Client in Account class.

Set the accountNum in Account class.

Then create a instance of Client

```
Client client = new Client(null, null, accountNum, null);
```

Then in Account class, set the client.

```
public void setClient( Client client )
{
    this.client = client;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Account` class should be like this:

```
public class Account {

    private long accountNum;
    private double balance;
    private Client client;
    private Random random = new Random();
    public Account(long accountNum){
         this.client = new Client(null, null, accountNum, null);
    }
 }
```